# Generate Unique Combinations When Duplicates Exist

Tags: r, combinations

My goal is to generate a unique list of combinations when we know that there may exist a similar combination of variables since part of the set being operated upon has duplicate values. So, the problem I am trying to solve is obtaining all combinations without replacement on non distinct items. **The solution needs to be general (i.e. works for any set of N elements with M values of distinct items. So, the solution should work with N = 4, M = 2 with (Var1 = Var2, Var3=Var4) or (Var1 = Var2 = Var3, Var4) etc.).** As a simple example that I am trying to do, take three variables: X,Y,Z

Classic Combinations are:

```
X    Y    Z
Y    Z
X    Z
Z
X    Y 
Y  
X
```

If we let X = Y, then we have:

```
X    X    Z
X    Z
X    Z
Z
X    X
X
X
```

Thus, we have two combinations that are not "unique": (X) and (X Z).

So, the list that I would want is:

```
X    X    Z
X    Z
Z
X    X
X
```

**Edit: Added case for when N=4 as recommended by @Sam Thomas**

If we expand this to N=4, we have: W,X,Y,Z

```
W    X    Y    Z
X    Y    Z
W    Y    Z
Y    Z
W    X    Z
X    Z
W    Z
Z
W    X    Y
X    Y
W    Y
Y
W    X
X
W
```

Here, we can have M=2 distinct elements in forms of either: (W=X, Y=Z), (X=Z,W=Y), (X=Y,W=Z), (W = X = Y, Z), (W = Z = Y, X), (W = Z = X, Y), or (X = Y = Z, W).

In the case of (W=X, Y=Z), we have:

```
W    W    Y    Y
W    Y    Y
W    Y    Y
Y    Y
W    W    Y
W    Y
W    Y
Y
W    W    Y
W    Y
W    Y
Y
W    W
W
W
```

The output should be:

```
W    W    Y    Y
W    Y    Y
Y    Y
W    W    Y
W    Y
Y
W    W
W
```

In the case of, (W = X = Y, Z) the matrix would initially look like:

```
W    W    W    Z
W    W    Z
W    W    Z
W    Z
W    W    Z
W    Z
W    Z
Z
W    W    W
W    W
W    W
W
W    W
W
W
```

The desired output would be:

```
W    W    W    Z
W    W    Z
W    Z
Z
W    W    W
W    W
W
```

**End Edit**

Using R, I already have a way to generate a list of all possible combinations in binary matrix form:

```
comb.mat = function(n){
     c = rep(list(1:0), n)
     expand.grid(c)
}

comb.mat(3)
```

This gives:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    1    1
2    0    1    1
3    1    0    1
4    0    0    1
5    1    1    0
6    0    1    0
7    1    0    0
8    0    0    0
```

If we consider Var1 = Var2, this structure would have redundancies. e.g. lines (2,3) and then (6,7) would represent the same object. Thus, the redundancy free version would be:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    1    1
2    0    1    1
4    0    0    1
5    1    1    0
6    0    1    0
8    0    0    0
```

To add "variable" values similar to the initial structure, I use:

```
nvars = ncol(m)

for(i in 1:nvars){
  m[m[,i]==1,i] = LETTERS[22+i]
}
```

To modify it so that Var1 = Var2, I just use:

```
  m[m[,i]=="Y",i] = "X"
```

Any suggestions on how I could move from the initial matrix to the later matrix?

Especially if we have more variables that are paired?

E.g. comb.mat(4), with: (Var1 = Var2, Var3 = Var4) or (Var1=Var2=Var3, Var4)

Comment: I think- see `?combn`

Comment: `combn` does not give the right structure e.g.

combn(c("X","Y","Z"), 2)

=>[["X" , "X",  "Y"], ["Y", "Z", "Z"]] 

Notice that X is repeated even though it is supplied only once. Similarly, Z is repeated.

Comment: Might help to show the result you are looking for in your updated example with `comb.mat(4)`

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion @SamThomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has all of the combinations, I believe.

```
m <- comb.mat(3)

res <- lapply(split(m, m$Var3), function(x, vars=c("Var1", "Var2")) {
   x[Reduce(`==`, x[vars]) | cumsum(Reduce(xor, x[vars])) == 1, ]
})

do.call(rbind, res)
    Var1 Var2 Var3
0.5    1    1    0
0.6    0    1    0
0.8    0    0    0
1.1    1    1    1
1.2    0    1    1
1.4    0    0    1
```

**Edit:**  Think this works for multiple equivalent variables- couldn't figure out a method without a `for` loop.  I'm sure there's a way with `Reduce` somehow.

And I *think* this gives the right combination of results, but if not let me know as it's late in the day and I'm a bit tired.

```
remove_dups <- function(m, vars) {
  for (k in 1:length(vars)) {
      res <- lapply(split(m, m[, !names(m) %in% vars[[k]]]), function(x, vn=vars[[k]]) {
        x[Reduce(`==`, x[vn]) | cumsum(Reduce(xor, x[vn])) == 1, ]
     })
     m <- do.call(rbind, res)
  }
  m
}

 m <- comb.mat(4)
 remove_dups(m, list(vars=c("Var1", "Var2"), vars=c("Var3", "Var4")))

           Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
0.0.0.0.16    0    0    0    0
0.0.1.0.12    0    0    1    0
0.0.1.1.4     0    0    1    1
0.1.0.0.14    0    1    0    0
0.1.1.0.10    0    1    1    0
0.1.1.1.2     0    1    1    1
1.1.0.0.13    1    1    0    0
1.1.1.0.9     1    1    1    0
1.1.1.1.1     1    1    1    1
```

Comment: I'm not sure this solution is able to scale since it relies upon the data being split on a variable. And also their is a constraint that is added in with regards to how many non-distinct variables you can have (e.g. Var1 = Var2, Var3 = Var4)

Comment: You can use `split` with multiple variables; e.g. `split(m, m[, c("Var3", "Var4")])`.  In my edited post I basically applied my function recursively for multiple pairs of variables